# Power Query - How to check if value in Column B exists in Column A?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need your help, I'm trying to work with Power Query but I'm struggling.

As you can see in the screenshot I've uploaded, I have 4 columns.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRa3O.png)

I want to check if the references in column "BPD reference" is somewhere in column "Reference", not only in the same row, but anywhere in column "Reference". Then add in new column if "BPD reference" is found, with "Yes" or "No".

Would you have an idea of what I could do here?

Thanks

I've tried the merge option with column "Reference" and "BPD reference" but I get 0 match values, I imagine the merge is only checking the same value on the same row.

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text along with your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (adjust for your step/field names):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    RefList = Source[Reference],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Reference", type text}, {"BPD Reference", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "BPD Found?", each if List.Contains(RefList, [BPD Reference]) then "Yes" else "no")
in
    #"Added Custom"
```